# using tuple with class as type C++

Tags: c++, return-value, stdtuple

I have defined a method for class Rettangolo like this

```
std::tuple<int, Point, Point> Rettangolo::interseca(Point *sol_p, Point *pvet){
//code
//code
return std::make_tuple(1, *pto1, *pto2); //example of return
//more code
}
```

My problem is to use the returned values in main. I need to do

```
(*it)->interseca(sol,normperp);
```

but basically i don't know how to save and so use the returned values since my tuple type isn't standard

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you say that your "tuple type isn't standard", what do you mean by that? What do you consider being a "standard" tuple type?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of the call to a variable:

```
std::tuple<int, Point, Point> tpl = (*it)->interseca(sol,normperp);
```

or

```
auto tpl = (*it)->interseca(sol,normperp);
```

Comment: Ok but i need to save data, especially the two returned points, as ptoi0, ptof0, how do i do that?

Comment: @squirrel Like I said.

Comment: @squirrel do you mean serialize by any chance?

Comment: @squirrel What do you mean by "save data"?